# Mock static method in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, mocking

How to mock a static extension method like `AsNoTracking` in `.NET Core 2.2` application for unit testing?

The problem is that I need to mock EF Core DbContext, but my code uses a static `AsNoTracking` method.

Comment: Could you provide example of code you would like to test? Dont know if UT should cover repository logic which could me mocked itself and for DAL you could simply use InMemoryDatabase instead of real context.

Comment: @LukaszBalazy I solved a problem in a proposed way, I registered DbContext with in-memory data provider for the Unit Testing project. It helped.

Comment: hi @VladislavFurdak  can you please provide one example how you have achieved unit testing of extension methods. I am facing the same problem with mongodb driver dbcontext for .net core. After googling a lot i found that "mole" nuget will help to mock the extension methods but it didn't helped me because "Mole" is not available for .net core. any leads would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @rajyadavI avoid overriding extension methods, i made in-memory dbcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pusporse of unit testing repositories you could use InMemoryDatabase, that would allow you to perform operations on database without acctualy affecting real databas.